# Why are these two summations in the calculation of the variance equal?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

**Background:** The screenshot below is the book solution to a 1st year probability question (Sheldon Ross self test 7.12). I understand everything except the last equality.

**My Question:** Is the red box equal to the blue box below? Can you show me step by step how to do it? I'm guessing there's some identity that will make it easier...

**My Attempt:** Unfortunately in lieu of being able to solve the question using math I put it in python and got different results for the red and blue box... but my script could be wrong. Thanks for your help.

```
n = 5

redBox = 0
for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(i+1,n+1):
        redBox += (i-1)*(j-n)
redBox = 2*redBox / ((n-2)**2 * (n-1))

blueBox = 0
for i in range(1,n):
    blueBox += (i-1)*(n-i)*(n-i-1)
blueBox = -blueBox / ((n-2)*(n-1)**2)

print(redBox,blueBox)
```

and for $n=5$ I get $\text{red box} = -0.277$ vs $\text{blue box} = -0.20833$.

Thanks.

---

**Book solution**

[image]

Comment: Crap I made an error with my script... looks like they are equal. Sorry about that. I'm still interested in learning how to solve it though using math. Thanks.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yes it is from a probability word problem. I actually understand all the probability bits of this particular problem, I was confused about how to do the "algebra" for the final equality. Not having a strong foundation for manipulating basic summations and setting up limits of integration has made learning basic probability harder than it has to be... but I am improving... I didn't want to call this an "algebra" problem because I know algebra for people here is not just stuff like $5x=15$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a first glance, the sum in the red box looks worse than it is. To get to the blue box you need only to collect common factors and use the formula

- $\sum_{k=1}^{N}k = \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$

$$2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{\color{green}{(i-1)}\cdot (j-n)}{\color{blue}{(n-2)(n-1)^2}}= \frac{2}{\color{blue}{(n-2)(n-1)^2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\color{green}{(i-1)}\boxed{\sum_{j=i+1}^n (j-n)}$$

For the "boxed" sum you may just write down some terms starting with $j=n$ to realize that this is nothing but

- $\boxed{\sum_{j=i+1}^n (j-n)} = -(0+1+\cdots +n - (i+1)) = -\sum_{k=1}^{N}k = -\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ with $N = n-(i+1)=n-i-1$.

So,
$$\boxed{\sum_{j=i+1}^n (j-n) = -\frac{(n-i-1)(n-i)}{2} }$$

Now, just "plug in" the box and rearrange a bit:

$$\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{(n-2)(n-1)^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(i-1)\boxed{\sum_{j=i+1}^n (j-n)} = $$ $$\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{(n-2)(n-1)^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(i-1)\left(\color{blue}{-}\frac{(n-i-1)(n-i)}{\color{blue}{2}} \right) = $$ $$\color{blue}{-}\frac{1}{(n-2)(n-1)^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(i-1)(n-i)(n-i-1)$$

Comment: Thanks for your help - your extra mark ups like colors/boxes make it very clear... fixing $j=n$ and then writing out some of the terms and identifying a familiar pattern is a strategy I will try going forward... I psyched myself out thinking a weird identity was necessary... but one of the few identities I have memorized is the sum of the first consecutive $n$ numbers... again thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.